# How to edit database file (mdb) of installed dotnet windows application?

Tags: microsoft-access, .net-framework, vb.net

I have installed a windows application (dotnet or Vb app, don't know what is it but it requires net framework) in my laptop running windows 10. It is an app for practicing mcqs. I can see program directory & other files in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program Directory\Program.exe". This directory has one MDB file which I can open with MS Access and can edit (e.g. Adding some extra MCQs) if I make a copy of it ,edit and replace original MDB file with edited file.
My problem is those changes I made are not appearing when I run this program, it stays the same. To test whether this app uses same MDB file when it runs, I deleted this MDB file and ran the program, to my surprise It ran without any problem. So I concluded that there must be another database file this program must be using (e.g in Appdata or any other directory). Is there any way to locate this active database file which this app uses so that I can edit it and changes will be reflected when I run this app ?
Also when I was using this app in Windows 7, whenever I tried to run this app after deleting MDB file in program directory, first it reinstalled app automatically ,created database file and then ran normally.
I think once installed in windows 10, a new database file is created somewhere else apart from that in program directory, which is used when app is executed. How to locate and edit that file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some research I found the solution. As I had thought windows 10 was using this database file from another location (virtual app data directory). Following is the path for this file, edits made in this file reflected successfully in the dotnet app.

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Program Directory\Database file